# Init! does not get inherited in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift2, realm

I'm currently experimenting with **RealmSwift** JSON support based on [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON), but got stuck with `initWithDictionary`. I moved extension to `RLMObjectBase`, and auto-generated swift code looks like:

```
extension RLMObjectBase {
  .....
    public init!(JSONDictionary dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
    public func JSONDictionary() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!

   ....
}
```

Which is seems ok to me. But Realm's `Object` (subclass of `RLMObjectBase`) does not inherit `init!(JSONDictionary dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)` by some reason. It's not available.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass inherits superclass initializers only if it does not define its own initializers.

You can define only convenience initializers in `RLMObjectBase` class extension:

```
extension RLMObjectBase {
    ...
    convenience init!(JSONDictionary dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) { ... }
    ...
}
```

and they will be inherited by subclass if it has no initializers:

```
class MyCustomRLMObject: RLMObjectBase {
   // no initializers
   ...
}

let object = MyCustomRLMObject(JSONDictionary: d)
```

Also you do not need to make it `public` if it used only in your application.

Similar example but for `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    convenience init(nibName: String) {
        self.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
}

let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController")
```

Comment: In both cases, subclass will not inherit initializers if it defines own?

Comment: If your subclass does not define initializers then it will inherit all superclass initializers, both designated and convenience.

Comment: What can you recommend to avoid or workaround this? **Realm-JSON** is written on obj-c. How to extend its initializers to **swift** with less possible pain?